# Как на C++ открыть фото и получить из него пиксели и их цвета?

Tags: android, c++

Мне нужно получить программно получить пиксели с фото, их цвета и размер фото в пикселях.

Язык: C++

ОС - Termux (Android 10).

Тип программы: Linux исполняемый файл (не статический, а динамический/нативный (bionic /system/bin/linker64))

ImageMagick (у меня стоит версия 7) не хочет собираться, поэтому он, а также CImg (он вроде бы юзает ImageMagick) мне не подходят.

Comment: А формат изображения какой вообще?

Comment: Ну, вообще хотелось бы поддержку разных форматов, в моём случае это непринципиально. Но давайте для начала хотя бы классический PNG.

Comment: [PNG](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/) имеет довольно простую структуру, можно разобрать самостоятельно. Ну или взять что-то готовое типа https://github.com/randy408/libspng/

Comment: Из интереса, хочу спросить ещё про BMP и JPG

Comment: Проще [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) ничего нет.